# Prove that for any two real numbers $x,y$ with $x\neq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that for any two real numbers $x,y$ with $x\neq 0$

$$2y \leq \frac{y^2}{x^2}+x^2$$

Comment: I tried to rearrange the inequality to get a true statement but I couldn't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

Explore the following expression $\left( x-\frac{y}{x}\right)^2$

Answer (score 3):

By AM-GM we obtain:
$$\frac{y^2}{x^2}+x^2\geq2\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{x^2}\cdot x^2}=2|y|\geq2y.$$
Done!